# ASP.NET Core 6 Angular SignalR template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, .net-6.0

What is the .NET template for a working ASP.NET Core 6 with SignalR and an Angular ClientApp that has a working WebSockets transport setup?

I can only get the ServerSideEvents transport to work.

```
dotnet new angular
```

doesn't have a working SignalR with websockets ...

I can add SignalR, but the websockets don't work

Comment: Try this links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Sample GitRepo https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.Samples/tree/main/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack

Answer (score 1):

You can configure clientside connection with your requirements. If you want websocket connection you have to configure like this:

```
  hubConnection =new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('your hub url here',HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build()
```